# Looking to increase my iMac's RAM

Tags: imac, memory

I am looking to increase the RAM of my iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Mid 2015). I found one on the Apple website, but it is $400. If I could find a better price, it would be amazing. I was looking around on Amazon, but don't know if the SDRAMs I found work with my iMac. Do you guys have any advise for how to tell whether or not the SDRAM is compatible with my iMac?

Comment: Can you provide the link on Apple's website where your found the product you are looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official RAM specifications are given by Apple here:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201191

Using the list, you need to

> Use Small Outline Dual Inline Memory Modules (SO-DIMM) that meet all of these criteria:
>
> - PC3-12800
> - Unbuffered
> - Nonparity
> - 204-pin
> - 1600MHz DDR3 SDRAM

Note that only 32 GB of RAM is officially supported.

Comment: Am I able to have more then just 32 GB RAM? Will the Mac not accept more?

Comment: @YusaMac205 Looking at search results, people have reported instability when they attempted 64.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.crucial.com is a great website for checking RAM and other hardware compatibility. They also have a scanner tool (http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner) to detect your computer type and give you a list of hardware that will work with your computer.  Generally, they offer competitive prices.

**Note:** This is not promotional just trying to provide one of the best sites  I have found. I am in no way affiliated with the website. The part about

> Generally, they offer competitive prices.

is not promotional because the OP said

> If I could find a better price, it would be amazing.

and therefore was looking for a "better price".

Comment: If those URLs change, this answer becomes useless, can you derive from those URLs information that can be used to answer the question, and provide them as supporting links?

Comment: Yes, but, the site doesn't show how to **figure out** what SDRAMs are compatible with my iMac. It just shows some products **they** made that are compatible.

Comment: @MathieuK. Totally agree except for the fact that OP commented on how expensive Apple was selling it for. Do you still think I should remove it?

Comment: @MathieuK. Ok. Well then it begs the question: If an OP asks a promotional question should you answer with a promotional answer? I will ask on Meta.

Comment: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3242/is-replying-to-a-promotional-question-with-a-promotional-answer-breaking-the-pro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76476/discussion-between-mathieu-k-and-josh).

Answer (score 1):

OWC and Macfixit specialise in Mac addons.  You need to double check the model number is right, but have a look here:

https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/iMac/Retina-5K/DDR3L
https://www.macfixit.com.au/apple-memory-ram/imac/imac-27-5k-retina-display-ram-memory-2014/sort-by/position/sort-direction/asc/

Note: This is not promotional just trying to provide a site.

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac intuitively already tells you what memory you should get to upgrade.

Start off by clicking on "About this Mac"

[image: About this Mac]

Then select the "Memory" tab.  It will tell you how much is installed, which slots are available (if any) and what the memory specs are for  your particular Mac.

[image: About this Mac Memory]

Click the "[Memory Upgrade Instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201191)"  link if you require more info.

As for memory, I use/recommend only trusted brands like the Crucial CT102464BF160B SODIMM.  A lifetime warranty and excellent customer service is worth (IMO) the few extra coins.